# RxJS All Individual Observables completed

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, rxjs6

I have an array of unique ID's and want to perform a bulk action (HTTP patch, delete etc) on them. That needs to be done individually and I need to display individual results.

As the requests are individual and it's responses should not affect each other. Results are displayed as they are received.

Every call is a separate Observable and what I'm looking for is a way to know when **all Observables have completed**.
The `onCompleted` method works only when there are no errors.

The goal is to prevent the button from being clicked while there are still call's being processed.

```
this.inProgress = {};
this.myIdArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

actionHandler(type) {

    this.inProgress[type] = true;

    const myAction = {
        patch       : id => this.patch(id, this.body),
        delete      : id => this.delete(id)
    };

    from(myIdArray)
        .pipe (
            tap(myAction[type])
        )
        .subscribe(
            res => {}, 
            err => {}, 
            () => this.inProgress[type] = false ); // onCompleted
}


delete(id) {
    this.myService.delete(id).subscribe(
        res => {} // confirm
        err => {} // show error
    );
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple observables and need to wait until all of them are finished forkJoin should help

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate this with [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin):

```js
var load = [1, 2, 3, 4].map(id => this.delete(id)); //Observable<T>[]

//do something when each Observable completes
load.forEach(o$ => o$.subscribe(resp => console.log(resp)));

//do something when ALL observables are complete
this.disableButton = true;
forkJoin(load).subscribe(() => this.disableButton = false);//all done!
```