# Angular with RxJs: Ensuring all observables are completed before

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have following code in angular using RxJs:

```
private loadData(id) {
    
        const inputData = .....

        this.backendservice.getData(inputData).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => {
            // do stuff
        });
        
}
```

Currently code deals with only a single id.
Now I want to get it working for multiple ids, and have a possible code structure like:

```
private loadData(ids) {

        const Map myMap = new Map();
        for(let id of ids) {
           const inputData = .....
           this.backendservice.getData(inputData).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => {
               myMap.set(inputData, data)
               // do stuff
           });
        }
        // do more stuff with myMap
}
```

I want to process all the ids before 'do more stuff' part is executed. I update a map in the subscribe code and use it afterwards.What is best way to achieve this using RxJs in angular?

Comment: Use forkJoin()...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to want to `forkJoin` an array of streams, then take the result and transform it into a `Map`.

I've added in some `console.log()` statements that can act as debug points to help you better arrive at/understand your solution. The general shape it can take might look like this:

```
private loadData(ids): void {

  forkJoin(
    ids.map(id => {
      const inputData = ...;
      return this.backendservice.getData(inputData).pipe(
        take(1),
        map(data => ({id, inputData, data})),
        tap(result => console.log(`Service call ${result.id} complete`))
      );
    })
  ).pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log("All Service calls complete and output as an array")),
    map(resultArray => {
      const myMap = new Map();
      for(const result of resultArray){
        myMap.set(result.inputData, result.data);
        console.log(`Results from call ${result.id} added to Map`);
      }
      return myMap;
    }),
    tap(_ => console.log("Call resuls transformed into a Map data structure"))
  ).subscribe(myMap => {
    // Do more stuff with myMap
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forkJoin` like below:

```
private loadData(ids) {
        let observables=[];
        for(let id of ids) {
           const inputData = .....
           observables.push(
               this.backendservice.getData(inputData).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => {
                    // do stuff
                });
           )
        }
        forkJoin(observables).subscribe(res=>{
            // do more stuff
        })       
}
```

Comment: In 'do stuff'  I am updating a map object which has 'inputData' as key, This map then i use in 'do more stuff'. It seems code structure you suggested won't work then.

Comment: As long as you declare it within the scope of loadData it should be fine. Whatever manipulations you do during do stuff will be available when you get to do more stuff

Comment: Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53088099/rxjs-all-individual-observables-completed doen't have 'res' in suscribe. It has () instead. Would it make difference?

Comment: In that question the outputs of the observables were not required (just the knowledge that they had all completed) and so there was no need. res will be an array of the outputs of your observables. If you have need of that information you can use it. Since the question didnt specify, I included it.

Comment: If we call subscribe inside push, then wont it mean we are not actually having an observable here.

Comment: No, the push should just take the observable returned by your function. Its subscribe will be called when its ready

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224843/discussion-between-mandroid-and-aditya-menon).